# Проблема с дискорд ботом

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Всем привет! Пишу на python бота для дискорда, бот должен одновременно и выполнять команды пример - `!mute` и работать как чат бот, то есть если в чат к примеру написали `привет` он должен что то ответить.
Код функций для теста:

```
@bot.command()
async def test (payloag):
    await payloag.send("It's command for tests.")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if (message.content == "hi"):
        await message.channel.send("Hello!")
```

Все бы хорошо, вот только вместе функции `@bot.event` и `@bot.command()` работать не хотят, по отдельности все работает как надо, но если их запустить вместе то работает только `@bot.event`. Пробовал сделать код в два параллельных потока но ничего не изменилось.

Можете подсказать как это починить? Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте это:

```
@bot.command()
async def test (payloag):
    await payloag.send("It's command for tests.")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if (message.content == "hi"):
        await message.channel.send("Hello!")
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Да, помогло, спасибо большое!